# How to stop long running request via another request

Tags: asp.net, request, cancellation

I have the following situation.I have a `ASP NET` application that i want to respond to `2` paths:

- `/run` - a long running task
- `/abort`

I would have a scenario where `client1` goes through `/run` (Starts the task) and after a couple of minutes `client2` would come through `/abort`  and would cancel the `task` of `client1`.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible ?

Yes, in a rather naïve approach, your Controller code would look like :

```
private static CancellationTokenSource Source {get;set;}

public void Run()
{

  try{
     Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
     DoLongJob(Source.Token);
  }
  catch
  {
    Source = null;
  }
}

public void Abort()
{
   if(Source!=null) Source.Cancel();
   Source = null;
}
```

You will pass the CancellationToken along the call chain of your `DoLongJob` method and sub calls. At different points in your code you will call `token.ThrowIfCAncellationResquested()`

Of course as said, this is very basic. It would only work with a single web server and a single task at a time.

Comment: The thing is it is not going to be only one task at a time.There will be many task starters and task stoppers.I would need to lookup long running tasks and cancel them when a request passes.Basically i will have `N` clients and each can start a long running task and cancel their task at any point of time.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian then you need to adapt the code above to handle a `Dictionnary` of  `CancellationTokenSource` which key would be a userId, or a taskId returned by `Run`

Comment: I did not know you can pause a `Task`.Is that via the `CancellationTokenSource`-s  `Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne` ? Wouldn't that block the underlying running thread from the thread-pool and make it unsable for other requests ?